# Cordova - How to not have a splash screen?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I don't want a splash screen for my Cordova project (Android and iOS), how to remove it? I tried to disable the splash screen plugin, but it continues to appear! How to solve?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" id="app.appname" version="1.0.0">
    <name>App name</name>
    <description>
        App name description
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
    </platform>
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
</widget>
```

Comment: In iOS there will be a launching screen that appears during the tie between the user requisition the app launch ad the tie the app is loaded and ready to run. This is not a "splash screen", some apps also have a splash screen after the launch screen, this is discouraged by Apple.

Comment: You can directly try removing/modifying from the source code of android and ios.

Comment: @SanifSS I don't believe that for something so simple and insignificant I must do this...

Comment: What cordova version are you using? I am using cordova from CLI V 5.4.1 and the default created app does not have the splash screen.

Comment: @HishamAbdel-Hafez I'm using Cordova 5.4.1 with Netbeans IDE.

Comment: can you edit the post with your config.xml file?

Comment: @HishamAbdel-Hafez done!

Comment: is this happening on both android and ios?

Comment: @HishamAbdel-Hafez I can't test it now on android, but I still see the cordova logo when the application opens on iOS emulator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls. do Change in config.xml as below:

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
```

Comment: Did this work for you, Joy? I have the same problem, but these two settings make no difference.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using cordova for your project, you can easily remove the splash screen by adding this tag to the config.xml

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

if the option:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
```

does not work.

You can do it putting this function onDeviceReady:

```
function onDeviceReady() { 
   navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}
```

in your config.xml must be splashscreen plugin

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
```

if this option does not work you can put splashscreen image by default in blank and put into your config.xml

```
<gap:splash src="splash.png" /
```

putting the splash.png image at the root of your project.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, finally! I struggled with the same problem. It seems - at least for the IOS build - that a a splash screen is mandatory no matter what I tried.

I found that I could add png files for each of the supported/recommended sizes, then the startup would use that one. I chose to have a proper picture, but you can create a blank (white or black) png if you do want.

Phonegap or IOS is picky on having all the various sizes available, so provide them all!

```
<platform name="ios">
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon.png"          height="57"  width="57" />
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png"       height="114" width="114" />
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40.png"       height="40"  width="40" />
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png"    height="80"  width="80" />
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50.png"       height="50"  width="50" />
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png"    height="100" width="100" />
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60.png"       height="60"  width="60" />
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png"    height="120" width="120" />
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png"    height="180" width="180" />
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"       height="72"  width="72" />
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png"    height="144" width="144" />
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76.png"       height="76"  width="76" />
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png"    height="152" width="152" />
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small.png"    height="29"  width="29" />
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" height="58"  width="58" />
    <icon platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" height="87"  width="87" />
    <splash src="splash.png" width="320" height="480" />

    <!-- iPhone and iPod touch -->
    <splash src="www/res/splash/ios/default.png" platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <splash src="www/res/splash/ios/default@2x.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />

    <!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
    <splash src="www/res/splash/ios/default-568h@2x.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

    <!-- iPhone 6 -->
    <splash src="www/res/splash/ios/default-667h@2x.png" platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
    <splash src="www/res/splash/ios/default-portrait-736h@3x.png" platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />
    <!--<splash src="www/res/splash/ios/default-landscape-736h@3x.png" platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />-->

    <!-- iPad -->
    <splash src="www/res/splash/ios/default-portrait.png" platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
    <!--<splash src="www/res/splash/ios/default-landscape.png" platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />-->

    <!-- Retina iPad -->
    <splash src="www/res/splash/ios/default-portrait@2x.png" platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
    <!--<splash src="www/res/splash/ios/default-landscape@2x.png" platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />-->
</platform>
```