# How to show welcome screen or tutorial screen in cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

Greetings. I am creating an app using cordova. Is there a way to show welcome screen or tutorial screen on start of the app. i want to show 3 or 4 slides with a button in the last slide. when user click the button i want the welcome screen to close. and i want to show welcome screen only the first time after the app is installed.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747746/cordova-how-to-not-have-a-splash-screen

Comment: @HareshChhelana no its not. the link that you gave was about splash screen. i am talking about tutorial screen. its different.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have created a separate welcome HTML/JS file  or jQuery page. Set this to show first everytime. At the end of showing this welcome page set a flag using localStorage.setItem().

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Then all you have to do is check for this flag when the app runs, if it is set just skip to whatever page you want the user to see.